# Unable to use env variable from prd environment context

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, cicd

Under settings in the repo created environment Variable Var1.

Below is github actions which will again call another template in different repo

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Pass_Input:
        description: 'test'
        required: true
        default: "From Github action 2"

jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    env: prd
    uses: your-org/your-repo/.github/workflows/option1.yml@main
    with:
      MT_NAME: "Calling from Github 2"
      MT_FOLDER: ${{ vars.var1 }}
```

I get following error:

```
 Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/option2.yml#L13
 The workflow is not valid. 
 .github/workflows/option2.yml (Line: 13, Col: 10): Unexpected value 'prd' 
 .github/workflows/option2.yml (Line: 14, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'uses'
```

Reference template of GHA is:

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      MT_NAME:
        description: 'MT Name'
        required: true
        type: string
        
      MT_FOLDER:
        type: string
        description: 'MT Folder location'
        required: true

jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: echo "${{ inputs.MT_NAME }}"
      - run: echo "${{ inputs.MT_FOLDER }}"
```

Please can somebody help to fix this issue

Comment: its working passing hardcode value and but not with env variable

Answer (score 0):

[I don't think you can pass the environment in the calling workflow the way you do](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#supported-keywords-for-jobs-that-call-a-reusable-workflow), you'll need to convert that to an input as well. Plus, to pass an environment you need to use `environment:` and not `env:`, the latter is for setting a job level environment variable, the former is to link a job to an environment defined in github. I know, confusing as hell.

The following workflow works for me:

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/callable.yml
    with:
      MT_NAME: "Calling from Github 2"
      MT_FOLDER: ${{ vars.var1 }}
      environment: 'prd'
```

and

```
name: Callable Workflow
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is testing out GitHub Actions 
on: 
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      MT_NAME:
        description: 'MT Name'
        required: true
        type: string
        
      MT_FOLDER:
        type: string
        description: 'MT Folder location'
        required: true

      environment:
        type: string
        required: true

jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      - run: echo "${{ inputs.MT_NAME }}"
      - run: echo "${{ inputs.MT_FOLDER }}"
```

Be sure to create the variable at the Repository level, you can't pass in an Environment level variable, as the calling workflow doesn't have access to the environment!

[image]

Result:

[image]

If the variable you're trying to reference is stored at the environment level...

[image]

You need to use a slightly different syntax:

```
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/callable.yml
    with:
      environment: 'prd'
      MT_FOLDER_VAR: var1 # <--- PASS IN THE VARIABLE NAME, NOT ITs VALUE
```

Then reference it in the callable workflow as follows:

```
jobs:
  Explore-GitHub-Actions:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      # ...
      - run: echo "${{ vars[inputs.MT_FOLDER_VAR] }}"
```

That will allow you to reference the variable stored at the environment through the input of the callable workflow.

[image]

Comment: getting empty value
Run echo ""
  echo ""
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}

Comment: I just ran a test with the exact workflows above and they work. Are you sure you saved the variable, and not a secret with the same name?

Comment: I just thought of another issue that may be plaguing you, I've updated my answer above.